# Connecting Salesforce sandbox with Mavensmate on Windows 10

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to install Mavensmate on a new windows machine to connect with my salesforce sandbox. I am getting a strange error whenever I try to download classes from my sandbox via mavensmate. The error message is
"Error initializing project: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users..\Documents\My Pictures'"

I am using VS code.
OS: Windows 10
Running Mavensmate as an administrator. Node JS is installed and tried everything else on the internet related to this error. Can anyone please help me out with this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to setup Mavensmate by changing the directory to another folder after going into settings.

P.S: Try to run Mavensmate as an administrator and disable your windows firewall and antivirus for few minutes.